# SSIS Script Task - VB looping issue

Tags: vb.net, ssis

The following script task in SSIS connects to a FTP server and is supposed to look for a file until it exists, then copy that file to a local folder.  It's doing everything correctly but instead of looking for the specific file, it's copying ALL files.

I've pieced the script together from various forums as I'm not a VB writer.  It appears the fileName.Contains is being ignored.

Any help would be great.  Thanks!

```
' Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Task
' Write scripts using Microsoft Visual Basic 2008.
' The ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.

Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime

<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute>
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)>
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase

    Enum ScriptResults
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    End Enum


    Public Sub Main()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50000)

        Dim VarCol As Variables = Nothing

        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::FileFound")
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockForWrite("User::FileName")


        Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(VarCol)


        Try
            'Create the connection to the ftp server
            Dim cm As ConnectionManager = Dts.Connections.Add("FTP")
            Dim strFolders As String()
            Dim strFiles As String()
            Dim fileCount As Int32

            fileCount = 0

            Dim fileName As String

            'Set the properties like username & password
            cm.Properties("ServerName").SetValue(cm, "ftp.testing.com")
            cm.Properties("ServerUserName").SetValue(cm, "username")  'user name
            cm.Properties("ServerPassword").SetValue(cm, "password") 'password
            Dim ftp As FtpClientConnection = New FtpClientConnection(cm.AcquireConnection(Nothing))

            'Connects to the ftp server
            ftp.Connect()
            ftp.SetWorkingDirectory("/testing")
            ftp.GetListing(strFolders, strFiles)

            For Each fileName In strFiles

                If fileName.Contains("test.xml") Then 'file has such word in its name

                    ftp.ReceiveFiles(strFiles, "\\FTPSERVER\c$\FTP FILES\testing", True, False)  'download file if found

                    fileCount = fileCount + 1

                    VarCol("User::FileFound").Value = fileName
                    VarCol("User::FileFound").Value = True

                Else

                    VarCol("User::FileFound").Value = False

                End If

            Next
            ftp.Close()
            VarCol.Unlock()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
        End Try
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: in your ftp.ReceiveFiles call you are passing it strFiles, that i s alist of all the files, I think you may want to pass it just the fileName variable?

Comment: If I change strFiles to fileName, I get this error:  'String' cannot be converted to 'String()'

Comment: Ok, the ftp.ReceiveFiles needs an a String() and fileName is just a String.  You could build out a new array of files that match your list.  So in your fileName.contains if statement appen all the filenames to a String() array and then after you loop through all your fileNames then call the ftp.ReceiveFiles with only the files that you populated in your new string array that matched.

Comment: That makes sense, but unsure how to write that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am not up on VB code so the syntax is most likely not right but the logic here should do what you need (you will just have to update to match VB syntax).  I put comments in the code to show what I am doing and also a problem with returning one of the file names in your current logic (I did not fix that I just pointed it out).

```
//declare string array to pass to your FTP call for only matching fiels
Dim FileNameListMatching as String() 

For Each fileName In strFiles

                If fileName.Contains("test.xml") Then 'file has such word in its name
                    // then if the file name matches in the if above, add that filename at the fileCount location into the string array
                    FileNameListMatching(fileCount) = fileName


                    fileCount = fileCount + 1

                    // this will have a problem here though because you are populating a variable with the fileName, but if there is more then 1 fileName found in your logic, it will overwrite it with only the most recent file name.  The True value is fine, because you dont care if there is more then 1 for that, but the file name returned will only give you the most recent file name if more then 1
                    VarCol("User::FileFound").Value = fileName
                    VarCol("User::FileFound").Value = True

                Else

                    VarCol("User::FileFound").Value = False

                End If

            Next

    -- then if filecount is > 0 then call your FTP to copy files
    if fileCount > 0
        ftp.ReceiveFiles(FileNameListMatching, "\\FTPSERVER\c$\FTP FILES\testing", True, False)  'download file if found
```

Comment: I've tried a few iterations of this, but my end result does not return anything.

Comment: Does not return anything?  What do you mean?  Can you step through the code and see where any problems are?  What values are being set, where?  Are they not being set at all?

Comment: Before adjusting the code, I would retrieve all files in the FTP directory to my local directory.  After adjusting the code per your specs, the script compiles successfully but does not retrieve any files.

Comment: If you retrieve all the files from the FTP site first, then the code above will not do anything because it already pulled all the files from the FTP site so there is nothing to do?  So if you loop through all the file names AFTER you pulled them from the FTP site, the list of files will be empty because there are no files on the FTP site anymore.  So the looping and if statement will never be hit because the loop will have nothing to loop through?  Have you tried stepping into your code in debugging and seeing the what values are in what variables?